# Is there a point in creating a conda package from an PyPI package?

Tags: python, conda

If one has a pure Python package already on pypi.org, is there any advantage of providing a conda package?

My assumption was that conda is really useful, if you have dependencies outside of the Python eco system. It then helps to have reliable builds. But is there something else? Is it in the end just personal preference?
[The tutorial](https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html#overview) didn't even mention the question when a conda package is (not) necessary.

Comment: More exposure perhaps? Seems like many new users get told to install Anaconda and then use `conda install`. While PyPI packages can be mixed in, [it's definitely finicky](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/). On your side, with [Conda Forge's auto-generation of Pull Requests](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/updating_pkgs.html#pushing-to-regro-cf-autotick-bot-branch) whenever you push to PyPI, it's rather simple to maintain.